# Grails UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter configuration issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-config

I am a newbie to groovy Grails frameworks. We have a requirement wherein we need to establish the database connection at runtime since each application user has  unique credentials for getting the db connection. We found that we could make use of Spring provided API UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter for achieving our goal. But when we try running the application after adding the configuration for UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter, we get the following error

---

[main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
                    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
                    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
                    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
                    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
                    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
                    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
                    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
                    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
                    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
                    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
                    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
                    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:33)
                    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
                    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
                    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
                    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
                    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
                    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
                    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
                    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
                    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
                    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
                    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
                    ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
                    ... 23 more
    ***Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object***
                    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
                    ... 23 more

---

**we have configured the UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter in the resources.groovy as follows**

```
     beans = {

            targetDataSource(DriverManagerDataSource){
                            driverClassName= "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                            url= "jdbc:oracle:oci:@dbname"
            }

            dataSource(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter){
                            targetDataSource= ref("targetDataSource")
                            username = "username"
                            password = "password"
            }

            sessionFactory(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) {
                            dataSource = dataSource
                            hibernateProperties = [ "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto":"create-drop",
                                                     "hibernate.show_sql":true ,
                                                     "hibernate.dialect":"org.hibernate.dialect.O                                                          racle10gDialect" ]
            }
```

}

Comment: Are you using any extra plugins? what is `Script1.groovy`?

Comment: Also, it's best to paste the full stack trace (you should be able to find it in 'target/stacktrace.log') into something like pastebin.com so we can look at it there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand the question, what it's an application user, why do not have multiple applications with one single user each (database user)....

Grails does need a DataSource to startup...

Or an application user is somebody that is logging in the app (Multitenancy)
http://www.grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant